# How can I unite a character value with the one above it in a data frame conditionally

Tags: r

| Time | Compound_Names |
| --- | --- |
| 2.105 | Ethanol, 2-(vinyloxy)- --- |
| 2.490 | Methoxyacetic acid, 2-methylpropyl --- |
| NA | ester |
| 2.675 | Hexanal --- |

I am looking for a way to comb through my dataset and when a situation like row 3 appears, combine the Compound name text with the row above it. I need to turn that table into:

| Time | Compound_Names |
| --- | --- |
| 2.105 | Ethanol, 2-(vinyloxy)- --- |
| 2.490 | Methoxyacetic acid, 2-methylpropyl --- ester |
| 2.675 | Hexanal --- |

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this assuming you data.frame named `df`

```
for (i in seq_along(df$Time)){
    if(is.na(df$Time[[i]])) 
        df$Compound_Names[[i-1]] <- paste(df$Compound_Names[[i-1]] ,
                                          df$Compound_Names[[i]] , sep = "---" )
}
df <- na.omit(df)
```